# Angular Routing Params issue

Tags: angularjs, routes

I am using a module where I add in my first controller which is taking a service as a dependency. All the service is doing is bringing in some data.
Then I have a show function which I am adding on an anchor element in my view in order to be able to click on the the first name and then get the user's details.

My second controller takes the data from the first controller and then using $routeParams I am trying to show the data on the user view. 
Is there something I am doing wrong here?

```js
(function() {

  var app = angular.module('test');

  app.controller('testCtrl', ['$scope', 'testFactory', '$location', function($scope, testFactory, $location) {

    testFactory.getContact().then(function(data) {
         $scope.contacts = data.data;
     });

     $scope.show = function(firstname) {
       $location.path('main/' + firstname);
     };

  }]);

  app.controller('userCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams', function($scope, $routeParams) {
      $scope.user = $scope.contacts[$routeParams.firstname];
  }]);

}());
```

These are the routes

```js
(function() {

  var app = angular.module('test', ["ngRoute"]);

  app.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

    $routeProvider
        .when("/main", {
          templateUrl: "main.html",
          controller: "testCtrl"
        })
        .when("/main/:firstname", {
          templateUrl: "contact.html",
          controller: "userCtrl"
        })
        .otherwise({redirectTo:"/main"});

        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
  });

}());
```

This is the error I am getting in my console:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'any1' of undefined
```

where any1 is the is the first name.

Comment: you are assuming that scopes are shared across controllers, they aren't, each is isolated. `$scope.contacts` doesn't exist in `userCtrl`. Need to use a factory/service to share across controllers

Comment: Thank you for coming back to me. So should I be passing them on this controller again from the service testFactory.getContact()

Comment: that would be simplest for now. You can cache the requests also using options in `$http` if that helps